# Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned is a known node ?

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch, sharding

I am running an elastic search version 4.1 on windows 8.  I tried to index a document through java. When running a JUNIT test the error appears as below.

```
org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException: [wms][3] Primary shard is not active or isn't assigned is a known node. Timeout: [1m], request: index {[wms][video][AUpdb-bMQ3rfSDgdctGY], source[{
    "fleetNumber": "45",
    "timestamp": "1245657888",
    "geoTag": "73.0012312,-123.00909",
    "videoName": "timestamp.mjpeg",
    "content": "ASD123124NMMM"
}]}
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.retryBecauseUnavailable(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:784)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.doStart(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:402)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$3.onTimeout(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:500)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateObserver$ObserverClusterStateListener.onTimeout(ClusterStateObserver.java:239)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$NotifyTimeout.run(InternalClusterService.java:497)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I can not figure out, why causes this error to happen. When a delete data or index it works fine. 
What might be the possible cause of it.

Comment: If you had at some point more nodes in your cluster and you stopped one where the primary shard was located, then this could be one of the reasons for the error above.

Comment: This error appeared to me, when I tried to search data from sense plugin adding some filter in body in chrome while I forget to add _search tag. The result is that it added that filter content as well to the schema.  After that i am not able to query or do other operations. Could you please tell me how to resolve it, if such problem comes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

you should look at that link:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-allocation.html

and that part in particular:

> cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low controls the low
>   watermark for disk usage. It defaults to 85%, meaning ES will not
>   allocate new shards to nodes once they have more than 85% disk used.
>   It can also be set to an absolute byte value (like 500mb) to prevent
>   ES from allocating shards if less than the configured amount of space
>   is available.
>
> cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high controls the high
>   watermark. It defaults to 90%, meaning ES will attempt to relocate
>   shards to another node if the node disk usage rises above 90%. It can
>   also be set to an absolute byte value (similar to the low watermark)
>   to relocate shards once less than the configured amount of space is
>   available on the node.

Comment: In my case, there is still a lot of free space in HDD

Comment: thanks (+1) - this was helpful. We had run out of HD space on our application server on the cloud and had resized it and increased the partition size. The application ran fine but ES had to be restarted after the change which we did not do and which is why we were getting the above error on ES.

Comment: The link to that page is gone.  Could you reproduce the useful bits here?

Answer (score 11):

**The Problem**:  seems that elasticsearch stops sending data to kibana as the disk space is exceeded. You get `org.elasticsearch.action.UnavailableShardsException` and timeout based on the fact that your ***primary shard is not active***. To strengthen the theory  - run `sudo df -h` and You'll probably might get high percentages of data volumes from `/var/data` in your machine.

**Explanation**: according to [documentation on elasticserach disk space shard allocation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html), Elasticsearch considers the available disk space on a node before deciding whether to allocate new shards to that node or to actively relocate shards away from that node. You have 4 variables that need to be set in order to override the default disk space shard allocation

> 1.**cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled** Defaults to true.
>   Set to false to disable the disk allocation decider.
>   2.**cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low** Controls the low
>   watermark for disk usage. It defaults to 85%, meaning that
>   Elasticsearch will not allocate shards to nodes that have more than
>   85% disk used. It can also be set to an absolute byte value (like
>   500mb) to prevent Elasticsearch from allocating shards if less than
>   the specified amount of space is available. This setting has no effect
>   on the primary shards of newly-created indices but will prevent their
>   replicas from being allocated.
>
> 3.**cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high** Controls the high
>   watermark. It defaults to 90%, meaning that Elasticsearch will attempt
>   to relocate shards away from a node whose disk usage is above 90%. It
>   can also be set to an absolute byte value (similarly to the low
>   watermark) to relocate shards away from a node if it has less than the
>   specified amount of free space. This setting affects the allocation of
>   all shards, whether previously allocated or not.
>
> 4.**cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage** Controls the
>   flood stage watermark. It defaults to 95%, meaning that Elasticsearch
>   enforces a read-only index block (index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete)
>   on every index that has one or more shards allocated on the node that
>   has at least one disk exceeding the flood stage. This is a last resort
>   to prevent nodes from running out of disk space. The index block is
>   automatically released once the disk utilization falls below the high
>   watermark.

**Solution:** Now lets perform an api call ,edit the configuration ,and increase the disk space shard allocation limitation (from 90 defaults to 95%-97%):

```
 curl -XPUT -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' 
-d '{  "transient":{
 "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.low":"95%",
"cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.high": "97%",
"cluster.routing.allocation.disk.watermark.flood_stage": "98%",
"cluster.info.update.interval": "1m"
}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the culprit was port 9300. It was blocked.

> Elasticsearch will bind to a single port for both HTTP and the
>   node/transport APIs.
>
> It'll try the lowest available port first, and if it is already taken,
>   try the next. If you run a single node on your machine, it'll only
>   bind to 9200 and 9300.

So I unblocked port 9300 and I was good to go.

In REDHAT linux to unblock a port.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9300/tcp --permanent
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo iptables-save | grep 9300
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same error and in my case, I had multiple master and data nodes. Master nodes were added to the load balancer but data nodes were not. So master wasn't able to communicate with the data node.

As soon as I brought all the data nodes in the load balancer, my problem was fixed.