# Connection Timeout with Elasticsearch

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()

doc = {
    'author': 'kimchy',
    'text': 'Elasticsearch: cool. bonsai cool.',
    'timestamp': datetime(2010, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
}
res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc)
print(res['created'])
```

This simples code is returning the following error:

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))
```

Very strange, because the server is ready and set (http://localhost:9200/ is returning some json).

Answer (score 122):

By default, the timeout value is set to 10 secs. If one wants to change the global timeout value, this can be achieved by setting the flag **timeout=your-time** while creating the object.

If you have already created the object without specifying the timeout value, then you can set the timeout value for particular request by using **request_timeout=your-time** flag in the query.

```
es.search(index="my_index",
          doc_type="document",
          body=get_req_body(),
          request_timeout=30)
```

Comment: Can this be set to 60 ? i am getting timeout even after setting it 30

Comment: @Kishan how big is your body of the doc ?

Comment: Hi, @RohitPatwa my problem was solved by reducing the length of the document. I don't remember how big the body was right now. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: What if my boss won't let me change the timeout and it fails on a single record?

Answer (score 42):

Try setting timeout in Elasticsearch initialization:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': HOST_ADDRESS, 'port': THE_PORT}], timeout=30)
```

You can even set `retry_on_timeout` to `True` and give the `max_retries` an optional number:

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': HOST_ADDRESS, 'port': THE_PORT}], timeout=30, max_retries=10, retry_on_timeout=True)
```

Answer (score 21):

The connection timed out problem could occur if you are using Amazon Elastic Search service.

```
es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'xxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', 'port': 443,  'use_ssl': True}])
```

The above python code where you override the default port from 9200 to 443 and setting the SSL to true will resolve the issue.

If no port is specified, it is trying to connect to the port 9200 in the specified host and fails after time out

Comment: Or you can use port 80 es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'xxxxxx.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com', 'port': 80}])

Answer (score 8):

This is nothing to do with increasing your timeout to 30 seconds.
Do people actually think that elastic search should need up to 30 seconds to return one tiny hit?

The way I fixed this problem was go to **config/elasticsearch.yml**
uncomment the following

```
http.port: 9200
network.host: 'localhost'
```

Network.host  might be set to 192.168.0.1 which might work  But I just changed it to 'localhost'

Comment: If the server is too busy, yes, you can have this error with one tiny hit.

Comment: or if there's an issue with DNS resolve, there are a lot of reasons for a timeout

Answer (score 6):

Note that one of the common reasons for timeouts when doing `es.search` (or `es.index`) is large query size. For example, in my case of a pretty large ES index size (> 3M documents), doing a search for a query with 30 words took around 2 seconds, while doing a search for a query with 400 words took over 18 seconds. So for a sufficiently large query even timeout=30 won't save you. An easy solution is to crop the query to the size that can be answered below the timeout.

Increasing timeout or doing retries on timeout will help you if the cause was in traffic, otherwise this might be your culprit.

Answer (score 5):

`elasticsearch.exceptions.ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))`
mean the request didn't end in the specified time (by default, timeout=10).

This will work with 30 seconds :

`res = es.index(index="test-index", doc_type='tweet', id=1, body=doc, timeout=30)`

Answer (score 5):

The reasons for the timeout could be many and it seems **worth checking the logs on elasticsearch** side (`logs/elasticsearch.log`) to see the detailed error. In our case, the error on ES was:

```
primary shard is not active Timeout: [1m]
```

As described in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025994/1526703), this was because our disk was full. We had resized it (and the partition) a day ago to take care of that but ES needs to be restarted if the high/low watermark has been hit once (we are on 5.5.x) which we had not done.

Simply restarting the ES on production resolved the issue for us.

Answer (score 2):

my personal problem was solved with `(timeout = 10000)` which was practically never reached because the entries on server were only 7.000 but it had heavy traffic and its resources were being hogged and that was why the connection was dropping

Answer (score 2):

Two options that help:

## 1: increase the timeout

Setting a timeout solved this problem for me. Note that newer versions need a unit, e.g. `timeout="60s"`:

```py
es.index(index=index_name, doc_type="domains", id=domain.id, body=body, timeout="60s")
```

Without a unit, for example by setting `timeout=60`, you'll get

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'illegal_argument_exception', 'failed to parse setting [timeout] with value [60] as a time value: unit is missing or unrecognized')
```

## 2: reduce text length

It also helps to reduce the text length, e.g. by cutting of long texts, so elastic can store the text faster which will avoid timeouts, too:

```
es.index(index=index_name, doc_type="domains", id=domain.id, body=text[:5000], timeout="60s")
```

Comment: This won't work as the error is still there stating the timeout value as 10

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error while running python elasticsearch client's es.index() method in a docker container.

The reason was that the disk space was >90% full. Elasticsearch cluster detects the disk usage and if its >90% full, it's unable to start the shard.

Once I freed up some space, connection timeout error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

so there are 2 different timeouts in ES. There is a client timeout when you connect to the instance and when you search for something.

for example

```
def get(self, json):
    return self.es.search(
        index="data",
        body=json
        , request_timeout=999
    )
```

I had this set as request_timeout=None but this does not mean that there is no timeout no it just reverts back to the default 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I got this timeout problem when trying out `elasticsearch 7.11.1` (installed using `apt install`) at port 9202 (9200 is in use by an `elasticsearch 6`) in ubuntu.

I googled around for nearly two hours before finally fixing it. It turns out I nneed to set (comment out) one line in `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticserch.yml`

```
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1"]  # earlier in the same file: node.name: node-1
```

I hope this may help someone.

Answer (score 0):

### extend the `requestTimeout`

```
client = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host          : 'http://localhost:9200',
        requestTimeout: 60000
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when specifying the `fields` option in my query for some reason. Removing the option made the query work (in OpenSearch at least):

Before:

```
elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es, index="my_index", query={"query": {"match_all": {}}, "fields": ["zip_code", "polygon"]}, size=5000, scroll="15m")
```

After:

```
elasticsearch.helpers.scan(es, index="my_index", query={"query": {"match_all": {}}}, size=5000, scroll="15m")
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

```py
> client.ping()
True
> client.info()
ObjectApiResponse({'name': .... })
```

Searching also worked, but indexing failed with an exception: `ConnectionTimeout: Connection timed out`.

The reason was that my disk was almost full. I freed up some space and then I could index without errors...