# ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host=u'localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

In local system elastic search works perfectly but when i'm trying to search in server system it shows in console : "ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeoutError(HTTPConnectionPool(host=u'localhost', port=9200): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287261/connection-timeout-with-elasticsearch follow the link ,it may help you

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the localhost value you are trying to connect to is a Unicode string `host=u'localhost`. Not sure how you are getting/assigning that value into a variable, but you should try to encode/convert it to ASCII so that it can be properly interpreted during the HTTP connection routine.