# connection error while using the python elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I tried to execute the below python code

```
from datetime import datetime
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)
```

The last statement through the below connection error.

```
ConnectionError: ConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x0000020DC5EEF6D8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No 
connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it) caused 
by: NewConnectionError(<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 
0x0000020DC5EEF6D8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No 
connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it)
```

Comment: Please state explicitly what the problem is and what you are trying to do.

Comment: chan you access Elasticsearch `elasticsearch:9200`?

Comment: i have historical user descriptions of the issue and its resolution. I want to provide the resolution recommendation when a new issue comes in .  For that when ever i get the new issue description, i want to do the elasticsearch on the historical issue descriptions and provide the quick resolution for the current issue.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have installed the only *elasticsearch client library* without installing the actual Elasticsearch in the computer.
Thus first install Elasticsearch as follows. [Download and Install](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/install-elasticsearch.html)

After you have downloaded a zip file(if you are using windows), into something like `c:\elasticsearch-7.5.2`

Go to a path like `C:\elasticsearch-7.5.2\bin` and run **elasticsearch.bat**

Then go to your browser and run http://localhost:9200/, You should get a response like [image] That means your elastic instance is running, so you can proceed with

```
es.indices.create(index='my-index', ignore=400)
```

---

In case you want a customization of the instance you can read out the tutorial [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/zip-windows.html)

If you get an error of ***connection error while using the python elasticsearch*** it has already been answered [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287261/connection-timeout-with-elasticsearch)