# elasticsearch multisearch timeout

Tags: python, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I've successfully used exact same code for different es host and it worked fine, however when I try to use it in different es host it is giving me 
`ConnectionTimeout: ConnectionTimeout caused by - ReadTimeout(HTTPSConnectionPool(host='search-production-fjexfhlafkqulrsxn5gkvzwnia.ap-northeast-2.es.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10))`

I've set `timeout` parameter inside each query when creating multi search, I've read https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html and documentation on multisearch however I cannot find any sort of timeout parameter.

My guess is I need to pass timeout parameter when creating es client or when creating multisearch. Any help?

my code is as follows:
awsauth = AWS4Auth('AKIAIALITIB7ZYLX3HFA', 'QWCb/I40T1UHfmPHm79mN3VU2ySwExhHh0PO/ri1', region, service)

```
es = Elasticsearch(
    hosts=[{'host': es_host, 'port': 443}],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)



 def create_msearch(dt):
    msearch = []
    for name in polygons:
        coordinates = polygons[name] 
        points = coord_list_to_dict(coordinates)

        msearch.append({})
        msearch.append({"_source":["date", "host","request_1","request_2", "location","status"], 
                             "query": 
                             {"bool" :
                              {"must": [{"match": {"request_3": "list"}}, 
                                        {"range":
                                         {"date":
                                          {"format":"strict_date_optional_time",
                                           "gte":f"{dt}T05:00:00.000Z",
                                           "lte":f"{dt}T10:00:00.000Z"}}}],
                               "filter" : {
                                   "geo_polygon" : {
                                       "location" : {
                                           "points" : points}}}}},
                             "size":"10000","timeout":"2h"})
    return msearch
response = es.msearch(index="index", body=create_msearch(date))
```

Is it were regular search query I can simply pass 'timeout' parameter just like I've done for each query inside msearch query.

However in the documentation https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch there is no parameter that deals with timeout in msearch.

According to [Connection Timeout with Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28287261/connection-timeout-with-elasticsearch) it says something about changing 'port' number, I've tried both 443, 9200 and both of them doesn't work.

EDIT: once I run the query since there are too many data to search it is using 99%of cpu thus taking a while to complete a search. It works when I run only two or three queries.

Comment: change the timeout in your request by : request_timeout=30

It s strange you got timeout with this query? How big are your documents? How many sharts / replica are present in your cluster?

Comment: You mean change timeout=2h to request_timeout=30? Ive done it before and it tells me it is not the right format. Each quert will have about 3000 and there will be about 70queries inside one msearch so 3000x70 documents. I have 5primary and 5 replica shards.

Comment: you can't fetch more than 10000 documents

Comment: Yeah but it will still fetch upto 10000docs.

Comment: Is that a secret key? If so, you may want to redact it. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258066/11107541